# Unable to get property 'map' of nested array in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue mapping an array in React.js. Below is the snippet of code I'm working on:

```
var MoveListItemComponent = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="move_list_item">
                 <p className="character_list_item_country">{this.props.move.move_name}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
});
var MoveListComponent = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    var moves = this.props.moveset.map(function(move){
        return(
        <MoveListItemComponent key={move.move_name} move={move} />
            );
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {moves}
        </div>
        );
}
});
var CharacterPage = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {character: {}};
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.props.service.findById(this.props.characterId).done(function(result) {
        this.setState({character: result});
    }.bind(this));
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderComponent text="Character Details"/>
            <div>
               <div className="charcater_page_top_info">
                   <img className="character_page_icon" src={this.state.character.icon} />       
                   <div className="character_page_info">
                       <h3 className="character_page_name">{this.state.character.name}</h3>
                       <p className="character_page_country">{this.state.character.country}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p className="character_page_tagline"><i>{this.state.character.tagline}</i></p>
                <div className="character_page_stats">
                </div>
                <div>
                      <h2>Special Moves</h2>
                      <p>{this.state.character.tagline}</p>
                      <MoveListComponent moveset={this.state.character.special_moves} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

And the data I'm accessing is:

```
     characters = [
                      {"id": 1, "name": 'Ryu', "country": 'Japan', "tagline":"You must defeat Sheng Long to stand a chance.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 7, "jump": 7, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/3/37/Portrait_SF2_Ryu.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ff9b9b"},
                      {"id": 2, "name": 'E. Honda', "country": 'Japan', "tagline":"Can't you do better than that?", "stats":{"power": 9, "speed": 6, "jump": 6, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/5/5a/Portrait_SF2_EHonda.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#9bb9ff"},
                      {"id": 3, "name": 'Blanka', "country": 'Brazil', "tagline":"Seeing you in action is a joke.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 6, "jump": 6, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/a/ad/Portrait_SF2_Blanka.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#a4cc9b"},
                      {"id": 4, "name": 'Guile', "country": 'USA', "tagline":"Go home and be a family man.", "stats":{"power": 8, "speed": 8, "jump": 7, "range": 8}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/4/4e/Portrait_SF2_Guile.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#f3ff8e"},
                      {"id": 5, "name": 'Ken', "country": 'USA', "tagline":"Attack me if you dare, I will crush you.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 7, "jump": 7, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/5/50/Portrait_SF2_Ken.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ff8466"},
                      {"id": 6, "name": 'Chun Li', "country": 'China', "tagline":"I'm the strongest woman in the world.", "stats":{"power": 6, "speed": 9, "jump": 9, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/e/e2/Portrait_SF2_ChunLi.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#6670ff"},
                      {"id": 7, "name": 'Zangief', "country": 'USSR', "tagline":"My strength is much greater than yours.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 5, "jump": 4, "range": 4}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/8/81/Portrait_SF2_Zangief.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ffa551"},
                      {"id": 8, "name": 'Dhalsim', "country": 'India', "tagline":"I will meditate and then destroy you.", "stats":{"power": 5, "speed": 4, "jump": 6, "range": 10}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/8/88/Portrait_SF2_Dhalsim.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ffea51"}
               ];
```

So everything renders nicely except the MoveListComponent. I'm pretty sure the issue is how it is mapped in the MoveListComponent class, I just don't know exactly what is wrong. I was using the same method to render a list of the all the characters, and that worked out well for me. Am I missing a reference to the list of special moves?

My full code can be seen here https://github.com/ChoragosDesigns/ChoragosDesigns.github.io. Thank you in advance.

Comment: r u getting any error ?

Comment: Yeah: Unable to get property 'map' of undefined or null reference

Comment: And where is the declaration of `characterService ` ?

Comment: characterService is in an external js file that is called by the index.html file. It works fine for me when creating the intial list of characters. If you go to https://choragosdesigns.github.io/ and use the search function, all the characters show up properly.

Comment: `componentDidMount` runs after your component was rendered, so `special_moves` are empty on first render of MoveListComponent.

Comment: I will try and populate an array of the moves in a state before that runs.

Comment: Yup, preferably move `findById` to `componentWillMount` or define your character as `{character: { special_moves: [] }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I focused on a comment @elmeister made about the list of special moves not being made yet. So I decided to keep how I was mapping pretty much the same, and then in the rendering of the final component, I put the SpecialMovesListComponent inside a variable.

```
var SpecialMoveComponent = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
               <h3 className="character_page_move_name">{this.props.move.move_name}</h3>
               <p className="character_page_move_steps"><i>{this.props.move.move_steps}</i></p>
        </div>
        );
}
});

var SpecialMoveListComponent = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    var special_moves = this.props.moves.map(function(move){
        return(
            <SpecialMoveComponent move={move} />
            );
    });
    return(
        <div className="special_move_list">
               {special_moves}
        </div>
        );
}
});


var CharacterPage = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {character: {}};
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.props.service.findById(this.props.characterId).done(function(result) {
        this.setState({character: result});
    }.bind(this));
},
render: function () {
    var special_move_list_component = "";
    //---When this component is mounted (or rendered) the special_moves isn't quite ready to exist. So first
    //     I check if it is ready, then render the component that handles the mapping, and put that in a variable
    //     which is called in this component's return 
    if(this.state.character.special_moves)
    {
        special_move_list_component = <SpecialMoveListComponent moves={this.state.character.special_moves} />;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderComponent text="Character Details"/>
            <div>
               <div className="charcater_page_top_info">
                   <img className="character_page_icon" src={this.state.character.icon} />       
                   <div className="character_page_info">
                       <h3 className="character_page_name">{this.state.character.name}</h3>
                       <p className="character_page_country">{this.state.character.country}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p className="character_page_tagline"><i>{this.state.character.tagline}</i></p>
                <h2 className="section_title">Special Moves</h2>
                {special_move_list_component}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Thank you everyone for your help, and hopefully this answer is clear enough for others.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in this line:

```
<MoveListComponent moveset={this.state.character.special_moves} />
```

character is an `array` of `object`, so to access the `special_moves` of any `object`, you need to specify the index also, use this:

```
<MoveListComponent moveset={this.state.character[0].special_moves} />
```

Or use `map` on this, like this:

```
{
    this.state.character.map( (item, i) => {
        return <MoveListComponent moveset={item.special_moves} />
    })
}
```

Check the character array:

```
character = [
    {...
       "special_moves": [
               {"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"},
               {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}
       ], 
    },{...}
]
```

Check the working code:

```js
var characters = [
  {"id": 1, "name": 'Ryu', "country": 'Japan', "tagline":"You must defeat Sheng Long to stand a chance.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 7, "jump": 7, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/3/37/Portrait_SF2_Ryu.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ff9b9b"},
  {"id": 2, "name": 'E. Honda', "country": 'Japan', "tagline":"Can't you do better than that?", "stats":{"power": 9, "speed": 6, "jump": 6, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/5/5a/Portrait_SF2_EHonda.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#9bb9ff"},
  {"id": 3, "name": 'Blanka', "country": 'Brazil', "tagline":"Seeing you in action is a joke.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 6, "jump": 6, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/a/ad/Portrait_SF2_Blanka.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#a4cc9b"},
  {"id": 4, "name": 'Guile', "country": 'USA', "tagline":"Go home and be a family man.", "stats":{"power": 8, "speed": 8, "jump": 7, "range": 8}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/4/4e/Portrait_SF2_Guile.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#f3ff8e"},
  {"id": 5, "name": 'Ken', "country": 'USA', "tagline":"Attack me if you dare, I will crush you.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 7, "jump": 7, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/5/50/Portrait_SF2_Ken.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ff8466"},
  {"id": 6, "name": 'Chun Li', "country": 'China', "tagline":"I'm the strongest woman in the world.", "stats":{"power": 6, "speed": 9, "jump": 9, "range": 7}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/e/e2/Portrait_SF2_ChunLi.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#6670ff"},
  {"id": 7, "name": 'Zangief', "country": 'USSR', "tagline":"My strength is much greater than yours.", "stats":{"power": 7, "speed": 5, "jump": 4, "range": 4}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/8/81/Portrait_SF2_Zangief.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ffa551"},
  {"id": 8, "name": 'Dhalsim', "country": 'India', "tagline":"I will meditate and then destroy you.", "stats":{"power": 5, "speed": 4, "jump": 6, "range": 10}, "special_moves":[{"move_name":"amove", "thesteps":"left, left, up"}, {"move_name":"asecondmove", "thesteps":"left, right, punch"}], "icon":'https://cdn.wikimg.net/strategywiki/images/8/88/Portrait_SF2_Dhalsim.png', "character_list_item_backgroundcolor": "#ffea51"}
];


var MoveListItemComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
     return (
        <div className="move_list_item">
            <p className="character_list_item_country">{this.props.move.move_name}</p>
        </div>
     );
  }
});

var MoveListComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var moves = this.props.moveset.map(function(move){
        return(
             <MoveListItemComponent key={move.move_name} move={move} />
        );
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {moves}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var CharacterPage = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {character: characters};
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
          <h2>Special Moves</h2>
          <p>{this.state.character[0].tagline}</p>
          {
             this.state.character.map( (item, i) => {
                return <MoveListComponent moveset={item.special_moves} />
             })
           }
        </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<CharacterPage/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I got a syntax error. Setting the index to get special_moves didn't work for me. Should be mapping the moveset inside the CharacterPage class or inside the MoveListComponent class?

Comment: whats the error when using index directly? map you need to use both the place, when you use map in CharacterPage page it will iterate the array character and send each special_moves to MoveListComponent component, now you need to use map again in MoveListComponent to iterate the special_moves array.

Comment: there is one issue in ur code, u set the initial value of variable as `{}`, instead of that set it to `[]`, like this: `return {character: []};`

Comment: Wouldn't setting the initial value of character as [ ] make it an array where as setting its initial value as { } keep it as an object? I got the original idea of this project following the example on this page http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/12/sample-mobile-application-with-react-and-cordova/ where that variable is kept as an empty object

Comment: Sorry, no I was able to fix it. I will answer it in a separate comment.